# How to use Room Database Viewmodel Observer in Android Foreground Service

Tags: android, service, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I have following view model and observer in A Fragment(in `onViewCreated`) which populates the recyelerview using adapter

```
commonOwnDBViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CommonOwnDBViewModel.class);
        Observer<List<FolderEntity>> notesObserver =
                FolderEntityList -> {
                    folderNameAdapter.setListManager(FolderEntityList);
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "" + FolderEntityList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                };
        commonOwnDBViewModel.getAllFolderEntityList
                ().observe(requireActivity(), notesObserver);
```

it gives me a list and works fine in the fragment now I want to use the same list in A service using Viewmodel and Observer how can we do that **how do we manage Lifecycle in service.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using normal service, use `LifecycleService`.

You can get the lifecycle of the service by calling `getLifecycle()` method and pass this lifecycle to your observer.

More details here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleService

Comment: so should we use commonOwnDBViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(getLifecycle()).get(CommonOwnDBViewModel.class); 
 ??